# How to create websites in shared folder using quickstart?

Tags: backups, drush

I am using [quickstart](http://drupal.org/project/quickstart) and I am able to create websites, run all drush commands, etc.

I am running Virtual Box on a Windows7 machine. i have setup a folder to be shared.

My problem: I am not able to create drupal sites (using drush qc --domain=mysite.dev") in that shared folder.

I want to create in that shared folder since I need access to the files from my windows environment also - for backup purposes, etc.

My terminal Output:

```
12:51:05 ~$ cd Desktop/
12:51:12 ~/Desktop$ cd shared
12:51:14 ~/Desktop/shared$ ls
DrupalPro_test.ova
12:51:15 ~/Desktop/shared$ drush qc --domain=neil.dev
                                                                     [ok]
Creating dns config (add neil.dev to /etc/hosts) ...                 [ok]
Command failed: neil.dev already exists...doing nothing              [error]
12:51:30 ~/Desktop/shared$ ls
DrupalPro_test.ova
12:51:36 ~/Desktop/shared$ ls
DrupalPro_test.ova
12:51:37 ~/Desktop/shared$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer on how to control where to store code. Trick was to use "--codepath=..." parameter.

## Controlling where files are to be stored

drush qc --domain=d7tries.dev --codepath=/home/drupalpro/websites/REPOSITORIES/my-drupal-experiments/d7tries.dev --makefile=/home/drupalpro/.drush/d7.make

Help at: https://drupal.org/node/819398